# Where is the App Store wishlist in iOS 11?

Tags: ios-appstore, ios

Ever since updating to iOS 11, I haven’t been able to locate my wish list anywhere in the App Store.

I had quite a few apps saved that I was planning on purchasing once the price dropped, but any trace of my wishlist seems to have vanished.

**How do I access my App wishlist in iOS 11?**

Comment: I saw this questions and was like "well duh, I've used it on the beta and it wasn't hard" but checking now I can't find it.

Answer (score 1):

The wish list has been completely removed from iOS 11 and iTunes 12.7.

[This article](http://gadgets.ndtv.com/mobiles/news/ios-11-removes-wish-list-from-the-app-store-1752564) confirms my statement:

> With iOS 11, you get a truckload of new features but you also lose some pretty useful things. Having already killed 32-bit apps on iOS, Apple has now removed wish lists from the App Store. Since Apple removed iOS apps from iTunes as well, there’s now no way to add apps to your wish list or to see which apps were there in your wish list on iOS 10.

You can share apps into Notes as a workaround.

Comment: Terrible data loss.

Answer (score -1):

We made a simple app as a replacement:
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/your-app-wishlist/id1287493475?l=de&ls=1&mt=8
free & no ads :)